# Is it possible to add root level menu of SublimeText?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I know we can configure **SublimeText** menu via sublime-menu files.

Is it possible to add a root level menu of SublimeText instead of subtree of the root menu?

The reason I ask is SublimeText is all about customize and configuration; and since I access to **Sublime Text > Preferences** so frequently, that I want the Preferences at not the subtree but the root level, where **menu bar** shows.

I use SublimeText3.

Comment: The Preferences menu is at the root level in Windows and Linux versions of ST2/3, but the standard for OSX applications is to have Preferences available under the "Application Name" menu. If you look at `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` (it exists in ST2, it's in Default.sublime-package in 3), you'll see that there's a top-level entry for a Preferences menu, but it doesn't appear in the menu on OSX for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

In ST2/3, configurations are JSON. Create a Main.sublime-menu file in your user directory. This contains a list of object entries. As an example,

```
[
    {
        "caption": "Custom",
        "mnemonic": "m",
        "id": "custom"
    }
]
```

This will create a "Custom" menu (at the top level). Of course, there aren't any sub menu entries so it's a little less useful. Below is a portion of the Menu file from one of my plugins (just to show how to specify a command). I listed under the "Custom" menu as an example.

```
[
    {
        "caption": "Custom",
        "mnemonic": "m",
        "id": "custom",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "caption": "Package Settings",
                "mnemonic": "P",
                "id": "package-settings",
                "children":
                [
                    {
                        "caption": "AdvancedNewFile",
                        "children":
                        [
                            {
                                "command": "open_file",
                                "args": {"file": "${packages}/AdvancedNewFile/README.md"},
                                "caption": "README"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I did this in ST3 on W7. I'm unsure how it will behave in other OS's, but I assume it would work.

Comment: Thank you for very concise tutorial and the example. In fact, this works in macOSX. Having said that, what I'd like to have is a shortcut to  Sublime Text > Preferences. Is there any way to Link to the exsisting menu item?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to link the directories.